# Is it possible to change video resolution while recording?

Tags: video, raspicam, raspivid

Is there possible to change video resolution from 640x480 to 1640x 1232 while is recording and vice versa?

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible without stopping the recording and restarting it with new parameters and a new output file.